# Filtering valid date -mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I am importing csv file with 2 fields i.e `sales,date`. Csv file will be like below

```
100,2014-07-01
100,2014-07-03
100,2014-07-04
100,garbaze date
```

I have migrated to mysql as below

```
id   date_input
100   2014-07-01
100   2014-07-3
100   2014-07-04
100   garbaze date
```

Unfortunately date_input is varchar , now i need to remove garbaze values and show real dates only

```
id   date_input
100   2014-07-01
100   2014-07-3
100   2014-07-04
```

I TRIED

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date_input  LIKE '20%'
```

but sometimes garbaze could be **20-date-garbaze**
 any ideas?

**I cannot make date_input's datatype date because i am doing loaddata to import records from csv to mysql. One datatype mismatch will halt all other imports**

Comment: If you stored your dates as dates and not strings this would be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert date into unix timestamps  and check

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE unix_timestamp(date_input) >0
```

**note : unix_timestamp will return 0(zero) for non date values**

Answer (score 0):

The function to convert from string to date is called [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and it returns `NULL` for illegal dates so that's basically all you need. You can also use it to copy your strings into an actual date column.